# Cocoa-Touch. What Exactly is the Difference Between These NSMutableData Methods?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsmutablearray, class-method, instance-method

One thing I'm a bit unclear on is the difference between these NSMutableArray Methods:

```
// Class Method Style

NSMutableData *myMutableDataInstance = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:WholeLottaData];
```

and

```
// Instance Method Style

NSMutableData *myMutableDataInstance = nil;

myMutableDataInstance = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:WholeLottaData]] autorelease];
```

Under the hood, what eactly is the class method doing here? How does it differ from the instance method?

Cheers,
Doug

Comment: By the way these methods belong to the NSMutableData, not to the NSMutableArray

Comment: Whoops. I edited the question. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class method creates and autoreleases an NSMutableArray object.

The instance method initialzes an object that you have to allocate yourself. The code you've written won't actually do anything, because `myMutableArrayInstance` is `nil`.  The class method is roughly equivalent to this:

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArrayInstance = [NSMutableArray alloc];
[myMutableArrayInstance initWithCapacity:WholeLottaData];
[myMutableArrayInstance autorelease];
```

And as Peter Hosey notes in comments, it really means this:

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArrayInstance = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]
                                           initWithCapacity:WholeLottaData]
                                           autorelease];
```

which will have different results from the above if the `initWithCapacity:` method returns a different object.

Comment: Or, more correctly, `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:WholeLottaData] autorelease]`. Remember that `init` methods can return a different instance, or release the receiver and return `nil` (after which point you are messaging a deallocated object).

Comment: Yes. Typing questions at 7am is a rather bug prone ;-). I edited the question. I see, so both flavors do an alloc, which is what I was really wondering about. In general, can I assume all class methods of this type - basically collections and NSMutableData - return an autoreleased object? Thanks, Kristopher.

Comment: Yes, class methods that return new instances will return autoreleased objects.